# set choices in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

```
class LeaveRequestStatus(IntEnum):
    open = 0
    accepted = 1
    rejected = 2
    closed = 3

class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=LeaveRequestStatus.open)
```

so i had to make this changes to the two classes but i still doesnt work

```
class LeaveRequestStatus(IntEnum):
    open = (0, 'Open')
    accepted = (1, 'Accepted')
    rejected = (2, 'Rejected')
    closed = (3, 'Closed')

class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LeaveRequestStatus, default=LeaveRequestStatus.open)
```

But it still doesn't work what i missing or what is not supposed to be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use: `choices=[(x.value, x.name) for x in LeaveRequestStatus]`
for first variant of you enums

Comment: its the choices

Comment: It should works. Please show you current version of code and say how you check if it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
class LeaveRequestStatus(IntEnum):
    open = 0
    accepted = 1
    rejected = 2
    closed = 3

class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=LeaveRequestStatus.open.value)
```

This was correct just don't forget to use `.value` when working with enums

Comment: This also helped

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using a tuple instead of a class

```
CHOICES = (
('open', ('0')),
('accepted', ('1')),
('rejected', ('2')),
('closed', ('3')),
```

)

Then just call it in your model field:

```
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```